# Опции cascade в Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Существует 7 вариантов опции `cascade` у `Hibernate`. Хотелось бы уточнить какого именно поведения ожидать от каждой из них. И хотя по названию эффект интуитивно ясен, но не везде так однозначно как хотелось бы.

Я опишу как я понимаю, а вы пожалуйста, поправьте меня там где я ошибаюсь, и дополните пробелы.

1. `none (default)` - никакие транзакции не приводят не к созданию, не к обновлению, не к удалению дочерних объектов.
2. `save` - при создании нового объекта дочерние так же создаются если их нет. А в остальных случаях действует опция `none`.
3. `update` - при обновлении объекта обновляются дочерние только если они есть и в них есть изменения. А в остальных случаях действует опция `none`.
4. `save-update` - 2 + 3 пункты.
5. `delete` - при удалении удаляются все дочерние.
6. `all` - 4 + 5 пункты.
7. `all-delete-orphan` - вообще не понятно что делает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Orphan removal - если у вас ассоциация 1 ко многим, и вы хотите удалить энтити, то достаточно всего лишь убрать его из коллекции. Это полезно, когда у вас двусторонняя связь. Без этой опции надо разрывать связь с обеих сторон.